# Confusing matching behaviour of pandas extract(all)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, substring, extract

I have a strange problem. But first, I want to match a hierarchy-based string onto the value of a column in a pandas data frame and count the occurrence of the current node and all of its children.

```
| index | hierarchystr          |
| ----- | --------------------- |
| 0     |  level0level00level000|
| 1     |  level0level01        |
| 2     |  level0level02level021|
| 3     |  level0level02level021|
| 4     |  level0level02level020|
| 5     |  level0level02level021|
| 6     |  level1level02level021|
| 7     |  level1level02level021|
| 8     |  level1level02level021|
| 9     |  level2level02level021|
```

Assume that there are 300k lines. Each node can have multiple children with again multiple children so on and so forth (here represented by level0-2 strings). Now I have a separate hierarchy where I extract the hierarchy strings from. Now to the problem:

```
#hstrs = ["level0", "level1", "level0level01", "level0level02", "level0level02level021"]
pat = "|".join(hstrs)
s = df.hierarchystr.str.extract('(' + pat + ')', expand=True)[0]
df1 = df.groupby(s).size().reset_index(name='Count')
df1 = df1[df1 > 200]
size = len(df1)
```

The size of the found matched substrings with occurrence greater than 200 differ every RUN! "level0" should match every row where the hierarchy str level0 is included and should build a group with all its subchildren and that size needs to be greater than 200.
Edit:// levelX is just an example, i have thousands of nodes, with different names and again thousands of different subchilds. The hstrs strings do not include each other, besides the parent nodes. (E.g. "parent1" is included in "parent1subchild1" and "parent1subchild2")

I traced it back to a different order of the hierarchy strings in the array hstrs. So I changed the code and compare each substring individually:

```
        for hstr in hstrs:
            s = df.hierarchystr.str.extract('(' + hstr + ')', expand=True)
            s2 = s.count()
            s3 = s2.values[0]
            if s3 > 200:
                list.append(hstr)
```

This is slow as hell, but the result sticks the same, no matter which order hstrs has. But for efficiency is it possible to do the same with only one regex matching group, all at once for all hstrs?

Edit://
expected output would be:

```
|index| 0                   | Count |
|-----|---------------------|-------|
|0    |level0               | 5     |
|1    |level1               | 3     |
|2    |level0level01        | 1     |
|3    |level0level02        | 4     |
|4    |level0level02level021| 3     |
```

Edit2://
it has something to do with the ordering of hstrs. I think with the match and stop after the first match the behavior of the extract method. If the ordering is different the hierarchy strings in the pat will be matched differently which results in different sizes of each group. A high hierarchy (short str) will be matched first, the lower hierarchy levels in the same pat won't be matched again. But IDK what to do against this behavior.

Edit3://
an alternative would be, but is also slow as hell:

```
for hstr in hstrs:
    s = df[df.hierarchystr.str.contains(fqn)]
    s2 = s.count()
    s3 = s2.values[0]
    if s3 > 200:
        beforeset.append(fqn)
```

Edit4://
I think what I am searching for is the opportunity to do a "group_by" with "contains" or "is in" for the hstrs. I am glad for every Idea. :)

Edit5://
Found a simple, but not satisfying alternative (but faster than the previous tries):

```
containing =[item for hierarchystr in df.hierarchystr for item in hstrs if item in hierarchystr]
        containing = Counter(containing)
        df1 = pd.DataFrame([containing]).T
        nodeNamesWithOver200 = df1[df1 > 200].dropna().index.values
```

Comment: Please give expected output

Comment: added expected output

Comment: I am able to break it to this point `s= df['hierarchystr'].str.split('level', expand=True).iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: 'level'+x)` Can you please explain using this output how you want combined? Why do you have `level0, level1` and not `level2`. Feel free to edit your question and include this output

Comment: "level" is here only an example. I have thousands of hierarchy nodes with different names. A simple split by text is unfortunately not an option. Think of the nodes as different and not including each other.

Comment: Repost this question with the exact definition you have given. There seems to be more activity and experienced coders about this time. Summaries it though.